# How to deal with dataset of different features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mlp

I am working to create an MLP model on a CEA Classification Dataset (Binary Classification). Each sample contains different 4 features, such as resistance and other values, each in its own range (resistance in hundreds, another in micros, etc.). I am still new to machine learning and this is the first real model to build. How can I deal with such data? I have tried feeding each sample to the neural network with a sigmoid activation function, but I am not getting accurate results. My assumption to deal with this kind of data is to scale it? If so, what are some resources which are useful to look at, since I do not quite understand when is scaling required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling your data can be an important step in building a machine-learning model, especially when working with neural networks. Scaling can help to ensure that all of the features in your dataset are on a similar scale, which can make it easier for the model to learn.

There are a few different ways to scale your data, such as normalization and standardization. Normalization is the process of scaling the data so that it has a minimum value of `0` and a maximum value of `1`. Standardization is the process of scaling the data so that it has a mean of `0` and a standard deviation of `1`.

When working with your CEA Classification dataset, it might be helpful to try both normalization and standardization to see which one works better for your specific dataset. You can use scikit-learn library's preprocessing functions like MinMaxScaler() and StandardScaler() for normalization and standardization respectively.

Additionally, it might be helpful to try different activation functions, such as ReLU or LeakyReLU, to see if they lead to more accurate results. Also, you can try adding more layers and neurons in your neural network to see if it improves the performance.

It's also important to remember that feature engineering, which includes the process of selecting the most important features, can be more important than scaling.